# What is the best method of plotting the average line/data of multiple CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I am currently working with 9 different csv files all testing similar samples of a material. The output of data looks similar to this:

```
Time,Displacement,Force,Flexure stress,Flexure strain (Displacement)
(s),(mm),(N),(MPa),(%)
"0.0000","0.0000","0.0007","0.0000","0.0000"
"0.0200","0.0000","0.0069","0.0004","0.0000"
"0.0400","0.0001","-0.0024","-0.0001","0.0003"
"0.0600","0.0005","0.0040","0.0002","0.0014"
"0.0800","0.0014","0.0106","0.0006","0.0041"
```

I was able to plot each file on the same plot using this code I have put together from several sources:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

### Set path to the folder containing the .csv files
PATH = 'my path' 

### Fetch all files in path
fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)

### Filter file name list for files ending with .csv
fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]

### Loop over all files
for file in fileNames:

    ### Read .csv file and append to list
    df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file, usecols = [3, 4], skiprows=2, names=['Stress', 'Strain'], header=None)
    
    strain_df = df['Strain']*0.01 
    side = 6.2 #mm
    stress_df = (df['Stress'])/(side**2) # N/mm**2

    ### Create line for every file
    plt.plot(strain_df, stress_df)

### Generate the plot

plt.xlabel(r'Strain $\epsilon$ (mm/mm)')
plt.ylabel(r'Stress $\sigma$ (N/mm$^2$)')
plt.title(r'Stress Strain Curve - 4$^\circ$C/min ')
plt.show()
```

This code block then gives a plot like this:
[image]

I am fine with how that ended up but I would really like to add a average line which I can add to this plot and also to compare to other materials tested in a similar way instead of having 40+ lines on the same plot. I'm not sure if the best way of doing this would be to create a new csv file that takes the average value of each row and column or if there is a way I can find the average in the loop I created. Any Tips would be greatly appreciated!

This is something similar to what I am looking for (the black line in the bottom plot):
[image]

Comment: Consider adding one new `df` column for each .csv file. Then you can easily compute [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) of what's in memory. Also, consider using [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), if only for the convenient automatic labeling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution and image result.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

### Set path to the folder containing the .csv files
PATH = './' 

### Fetch all files in path
fileNames = os.listdir(PATH)

### Filter file name list for files ending with .csv
fileNames = [file for file in fileNames if '.csv' in file]
count_fileNames = len(fileNames)
list_strain = []
list_stress = []
### Loop over all files
for file in fileNames:
    print("file: ", file)

    ### Read .csv file and append to list
    df = pd.read_csv(PATH + file, usecols = [3, 4], skiprows=2, names=['Stress', 'Strain'], header=None, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
    
    strain_df = df['Strain']*0.01
    side = 6.2 #mm
    stress_df = (df['Stress'])/(side**2) # N/mm**2

    list_strain.append(strain_df)
    list_stress.append(stress_df)
    ### Create line for every file
    plt.plot(strain_df, stress_df)

mean_strain = sum(list_strain) / count_fileNames
mean_stress = sum(list_stress) / count_fileNames
plt.plot(mean_strain, mean_stress, 'k')

### Generate the plot

plt.xlabel(r'Strain $\epsilon$ (mm/mm)')
plt.ylabel(r'Stress $\sigma$ (N/mm$^2$)')
plt.title(r'Stress Strain Curve - 4$^\circ$C/min ')
plt.show()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw58N.png)